# SELECT MAX from two tables returning a weird value

Tags: mysql

```
Table 'orders'   
    +----+-------+
    | id | refId |
    +----+-------+
    |  3 | 3     |
    |  7 | 5     |
    |  8 | 200   |
    |  9 | NULL  |
    | 10 | NULL  |
    | 21 | NULL  |
    +----+-------+

Table 'transactions'
    +----+-------+
    | id | refId |
    +----+-------+
    | 23 |   200 |
    | 24 |   201 |
    | 22 |   202 |
    | 26 |   203 |
    | 25 |   204 |
    | 27 |   205 |
    +----+-------+
```

So I got these two tables and I wanted to get the max value of refId(that would be 205)

What I'm using is the next query:

```
SELECT MAX( cacat ) 
FROM (

    SELECT refId AS cacat
    FROM orders
    UNION 
    SELECT refId AS cacat
    FROM transactions

    ) AS pla
```

->> returning

```
+------------+
| MAX(cacat) |
+------------+
|          5 |
+------------+
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are these values text?  Your query looks like it should be working to me.  Also, are you sure this is the actual data against which you ran your query?

Comment: Run these and tell us what you see: `SELECT MAX(refId) FROM orders` and this too 'SELECT MAX(refId) FROM transactions`

Comment: the values are varchar

Comment: SELECT MAX(refId) FROM transactions -> 205

Comment: column type of `refId `?

Comment: SELECT MAX(refId) FROM orders -> 5 (pretty weird as it should be 200 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the result you want would be to cast your text `refId` values to a number:

```
SELECT MAX( cacat ) 
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST(refId AS UNSIGNED) AS cacat FROM orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(refId AS UNSIGNED) FROM transactions
) AS pla
```

Note: Text are not numbers, and numbers are not text.  If you really need the `refId` column to behave like a number, then perhaps consider storing this information in some sort of MySQL numeric column.

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT MAX( cast(cacat as unsigned) ) 
FROM (

    SELECT refId AS cacat
    FROM orders
    UNION 
    SELECT refId AS cacat
    FROM transactions

    ) AS pla
```

Answer (score 0):

**WITH** abc **AS** 
(
SELECT refId FROM orders

**UNION**

SELECT refId FROM transactions

)

SELECT max(refId) from **abc**

Comment: MySQL supports table expressions from 8.0